# ggplot2 2.0.0 coloured boxplots and jitter with borders

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, jitter

I am trying to make a boxplot filled by a binary variable, with a facet grid. I also want to have jitter on top of the boxplots, but without getting them confused with the outliers. In order to fix this, I have added colour to the jitter, but by doing so, they meld in with the already coloured boxplots, as they are the same colour.

I really want to keep the colours the same, so is there a way to add borders to the jitter (or is there a different way to fix the outlier problem)?

Example code:

```
plot <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))+
   geom_boxplot(aes(fill = drv))+
   geom_jitter(width = .3, aes(colour =drv))
 #  facet_grid(. ~some_binary_variable, scales="free")
```

Comment: Try `geom_jitter(width = .3, aes(fill =class),shape=21)`.

Comment: you probably want to use the `outlier.shape=NA` argument for `geom_boxplot()` so you don't duplicate the dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filled plotting symbol (`21:25`, cf. `?pch`) and then use a white border to differentiate the points:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = drv))+
    geom_jitter(width = .3, aes(fill = drv), shape = 21, color = "white")
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you! I see now that I messed up when plotting the variables, so I edited that in my question. Will try to edit yours too if i can, so the graph looks prettier.